# Jetpack Compose retry test rule

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os, android-jetpack

I have a Jetpack Compose based app with next base test rule setup:

```
val activityComposeRule by lazy { createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity> }
// Barista retry rule if test failed
val flakyRule = FlakytestRule().allowFlakyAttemptsByDefault(2)
val permissionRule = ...

@get:Rule   
val rulechain:RuleChain = run {
 RuleChain.outerRule (permissionRule).around(activityComposeRule).around(flakyRule )
}
```

For node interaction, in test code use activityComposeRule

```
activityComposeRule.onNode(...)
```

The thing is when a test fails, it can't re-run tests - it fails with

```
Cannot call setContent twice per test!
```

I find a [solution](https://slack-chats.kotlinlang.org/t/511686/hello-everyone-blush-is-there-a-way-to-run-repeat-flaky-test) from devs in which they propose to use `createEmptyComposeRule()` with `ActivityScenario<T>`, which will looks like this

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createEmptyComposeRule()

@get:Rule
val flakyRule = FlakyTestRule().allowFlakyAttemptsByDefault(defaultAttempts = 10)

private lateinit var scenario: ActivityScenario<ComponentActivity>

@Before
fun setup() {
    scenario = ActivityScenario.launch(ComponentActivity::class.java)
}

@After
fun tearDown(){
    scenario.close()
}

@Test
@Repeat(times = 10)
fun test() {
        scenario.onActivity {
            it.setContent { ... }
        }
    }
```

but it will be a pain in the ass to refactor whole code.

Is there a way to rerun flaky test using Barista rule and without changing `createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>` ?

Thanks in advance

UPD. Similar issue at Google Tracker - [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235383900)